# How to get the div name in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the div name at `alert(name)`, but it gives as "undifined". The values come from a database. All other alerts are working fine.

Here is my HTML code.

```
<input class="rating form-control input-star-rate" id="<?php echo $rateid; ?>" name="<?php echo $arate_num; ?>" value="<?php echo $ratea; ?>" data-min="0" data-max="5" data-step="0.3" data-size="xs" style="display: none; text-align: center;" onchange="changeRate(this)"/>
```

Here is my javaScript code.

```
function changeRate(id) {
    var ratingValue = id.value;
    var ratingValue2 = parseFloat(ratingValue);
    alert(ratingValue2);

    var ratingValuePrevious = id.getAttribute('value');
    var ratingValuePrevious2 = parseFloat(ratingValuePrevious);
    alert(ratingValuePrevious2);

    var id = id.id;
    alert(id);

    var name = id.name;
    alert(name);
}
```

Comment: try `$('input').attr('name');`

Comment: Are you sure your $arate_num variable contains a value? When you press F12 and inspect the element in the developer tools does "name" have a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
var name = id.getAttribute('name');
alert(name);
```

Answer (score 4):

use getAttribute  in javascript

```
id.getAttribute("name");
```

or

in jquery

```
$(id).attr("name");
```

NOTE : in your code this will display `undefined`  `id.name` so change to `id.getAttribute("name");`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because you reassign `id` variable value inside a function:

```
function changeRate(id) {
    // ... 
    var id = id.id;
    // ...
}
```

after that `id.name` is undefined of course, because `id` is no longer a HTMLInputElement object, but just a string, which has no `name` property of course.

In general `id` is not very good name for DOM element parameter reference. Name it better `obj` to avoid confusion with `id` property:

```
function changeRate(obj) {
    var ratingValue = obj.value;
    var ratingValue2 = parseFloat(ratingValue);
    alert(ratingValue2);

    var ratingValuePrevious = obj.getAttribute('value');
    var ratingValuePrevious2 = parseFloat(ratingValuePrevious);
    alert(ratingValuePrevious2);

    var id = obj.id;
    alert(id);

    var name = obj.name;
    alert(name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't change your original `id variable` by assigning its id to the same. And try to use [getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute) like,

```
var myid = id.id; // don't change your original variable, use myid instead
alert(myid);

var name = id.getAttribute('name');
alert(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the id is alerted correctly, then the problem is only at that you overwrite the id to be id.id. Use different variable name for the id of your id input.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code and let me know if it works for you.

```
    var name = document.getElementById(id).attributes["name"].value;
    alert(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are calling the changeRate() function, but I guess if you are able to see the correct values in the alerts written before alert(name), then you are calling it correctly. 
Now coming the point of alert(name), as mentioned in the above comment **id.getAttribute("name");** should solve your problem.
Let us know the complete stacktrace if the issue is not resolved.